# Delphi: Setting connection timeout for TIdHttpServer

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

Using TIdHTTPServer (Indy 10.6), i want set a connection timeout for close slow or inactive client (client are common browser) and close all zombie connection after 60 seconds of inactivity. I have found Socket.ReadTimeout in TIdContext.Connection. Is this the right way? TIdHTTPServer already perform this (it seem have infinite timeout)?

```
WebServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
WebServer.SessionState := false;
WebServer.KeepAlive    := false;
WebServer.OnCommandGet := CustomOnCommandGet;

procedure CustomOnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
begin
    AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout := 60000;
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create('C:/file.zip', fmOpenRead or fmShareCompat);
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track, the `ReadTimeout` property can be used to disconnect slow/dead clients that do not send requests in a timely manner. However, you are setting `ReadTimeout` in the wrong place.

By the time an `OnCommand...` event is triggered, `TIdHTTPServer` has already read the client's request in full, so your new setting will not take effect until the *next* request on the same connection, if any.  So, you should set the `ReadTimeout` value in the `OnConnect` event instead:

```
WebServer.OnConnect := CustomOnConnect;

procedure CustomOnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout := 60000;
end;
```

Remember that HTTP is stateless.  Multiple HTTP requests can be sent on the same connection *only if* HTTP keep-alives are used, which is optional.  Without keep-alives, the server closes the connection after sending a response. A client would have to reconnect to send a new request.

You are setting the server's `KeepAlive` property to false, so there will not be any keep-alives honored, every request will be followed by a disconnect.  So, you need to set `ReadTimeout` in the `OnConnect` event to apply it to the sole request sent on each connection.  But, if you enable `KeepAlive`, and a client requests a keep-alive, then the `ReadTimeout` will apply to every request that client sends on the same connection, especially the first request.

Comment: ok, thank you! but why you have removed the part of your answer `[...] as such your ReadTimeout value will only be able to avoid slow/dead clients that cannot send requests in a timely manner.`. you think, in my case, "read timeout" is not useful for close dead/slow connection?

Comment: I removed that phrase because it didn't really fit in with the flow of the rest of the answer anymore as I was making edits. It still applies, though, so I have slipped it back in.